# PHP - Proper grouping of data and getting the in between data

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a table for booking:

```
id         room_id        start          end
1          1              2019-10-04     2019-10-14
2          1              2019-10-13     2019-10-22
3          1              2019-12-16     2019-12-25
4          1              2019-11-30     2019-12-18
```

Table for room:

```
id         name        type
1          002         1-A
2          005         3-B
```

So I just wanted a sample for only one roomtype `1-A` I wanted to group the booking using `foreach` to this output:

```
start_date => 2019-10-04      AND    end_date => 2019-10-22
start_date => 2019-11-30      AND    end_date => 2019-12-25
```

There should be 2 groups.

I tried using this

```
$new = array();
foreach($bookingArr as $booking) {
   $new[$booking->room_id][$booking->start][] = $booking;
}
```

But I dont get the output I wanted.

Comment: What output you want? Can You please share?

Comment: I assume it's because you use `$booking->start` in your array, not sure of your code, but you could use the start date of the week `2019-10-04` to group them together instead.

Comment: @Jaymin the output should be 2 groups like in the 3rd box

Comment: @NigelRen what do you mean by the start sir?

Comment: Your output is not making sense- maybe the room_id for the last 2 row in the booking table should be 2 instead of 1?

Comment: no sir I it is correct, because they are overlapping they should make into one group @dWinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to order results by start date.
after you need to implement intersection of date start-end periods.

assuming it's done the code may be smth similar to this one:

```
<?php
$bookingData = [
    [
        'room_type' => '1-A',
        'start'     => '2019-10-04',
        'end'       => '2019-10-14',
    ],
    [
        'room_type' => '1-A',
        'start'     => '2019-10-13',
        'end'       => '2019-10-22',
    ],
    [
        'room_type' => '1-A',
        'start'     => '2019-11-30',
        'end'       => '2019-12-18',
    ],
    [
        'room_type' => '1-A',
        'start'     => '2019-12-16',
        'end'       => '2019-12-25',
    ],
];

$output = [];
$k = -1;

foreach ($bookingData as $data) {
    $curr = $output[$k] ?? null;
    if ($curr !== null &&
        $data['start'] >= $curr['start'] &&
        $data['start'] <= $curr['end'] &&
        $data['end'] > $curr['end']) {
        $output[$k]['end'] = $data['end'];
    } else {
        $output[] = $data;
        $k++;
    }
}

foreach ($output as $item) {
    echo sprintf("start_date => %s AND end_date => %s\r\n", $item['start'], $item['end']);
}
```

[demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/fei9Ilq6aVLW7V3J)